# Local Cluster SSL Certificate invalid trust

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric

My local development (5 node) cluster have two stateless services installed. One .Net Core Web Gui service and one .Net Core WebAPI service.
Both are configured to use a https endpoint.
The certificates are self signed certificates and are added to both trusted root and personal (in both current user and localmachine).

I can access both endpoints using a local browser without getting any certificate errors. It says the connection is secure and the certificates are trusted.
So far so good.

But when my Web API services calls my Web Gui service, is says it cannot create a trusted connection.

Why can my local browser create a trusted connection but not the Service running in the local cluster?

Does a Node in a local cluster have it's own Certificate Store?

Comment: Can you use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to see more information about why the handshake failed?

Comment: Ok, I will try that and get back with the results. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the ServerCertificateValidateCallback function showed me that the problem is:
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot

But why does the Service report this, and not my Web Browser?

Comment: are you using the FQDN (not localhost) to call the service in both cases?

Comment: Yes I do, hostnames are added to the host file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I missed adding the certificates to the machine root and that's what caused the problem.

For local SSL to work, I needed to to add the self signed certificates to:

```
localmachine/my
localmachine/root
```

This lets services call services from within the local cluster.

```
currentuser/my
currentyser/root
```

This lets my browsers call my services without ssl errors.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: in your qn you said 'self signed certificates and are added to both trusted root and personal (in both current user and localmachine'

Comment: Yes, this was wrong of me. When I checked the certificate store I forgot to refresh the view so I didn't noticed that the certificates had been removed :(

Comment: Similar issue for me thanks! But in my case I was calling a localhost outside of SF on the same machine. The local machine certificate store didn't work for me until I realized there were 2 certs for Visual Studio, one for IIS Express and the other for Self-hosted. I just copied them both.